# Custom paging with Datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am fetching bulk records from database and show in jquery datatable and its very slow. I have an idea to achieve this in better way if any one can help me in this regard.

1- Get count of records and make paging (e.g 100/10 10 pages) and on click of every page I will get 10 record from DB.

Is this feasible approach or any one have better idea or example.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much faster if just do the paging, filtering and sorting (if you need this features) direct on server through a stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please quote me any example.

Comment: you can have a look at this  [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590341/Stored-Procedure-with-Sorting-Paging-and-Filtering) . Maybe it would help you.